# Linechart X Values with Labels

Tags: swift, charts, linechart, ios-charts

I am fetching from a Backend System some Metric Data in order show those in a Line Chart View. The X values equals the following date format e.g. 15:10:00 , 15:15:00 , 15:20:00, .. or 01.02.2019 : 14:30, 01.02.2019 : 15:30, 01.02.2019 : 16:30, ... . My problem is, that the ChartDataEntry for the X values only allows double as Type but I need the Values as above listed. Is there any way to add Label to my X values ?

Cheers Ertan

NA

```
func initializeChartView(xValue : [Double], yValue : [Any], chartLabel : String, chartViewLabel: String)
{
    chartView.data = nil
    for index in 0..<xValue.count {

        let dataEntry  = ChartDataEntry(x: xValue[index], y: yValue[index] as! Double)
        charDataEntry.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let line1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: charDataEntry, label: chartLabel)
    line1.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
    lineChartData.addDataSet(line1)
    chartView.data = lineChartData
    chartView.chartDescription?.text = "EEEAM"
    chartView.chartDescription?.textColor = UIColor.white
    line1.valueTextColor = NSUIColor.white
    chartView.legend.textColor = UIColor.white
    line1.lineWidth = 1
    line1.colors = [NSUIColor.green]
    chartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white
    chartView.leftAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.white
    chartView.renderer?.animator.animate(xAxisDuration: 0.3)
    line1.drawFilledEnabled = true
    line1.fillColor = NSUIColor.purple
}
```

Comment: You can get a TimeInterval from a Date, and TimeInterval is a Double. You need to create a custom class that conforms to IAxisValueFormatter and converts the Double (TimeInterval) to a formatted date string of your choosing. Then set the xAxis valueFormatter to your custom class. I don't recall, but there may be an example of this in their demo projects.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me :-)